# Selenium find_element_by_id - extract temporary element ID

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Writing an automation script to fill in a form (on a non-public website) using Selenium (Py 3.7), which includes selecting a value from a dropdown menu.

The element name of the value to be selected is static ('incorporationPlace') but the id changes for each new browser session. I would like to extract the element result for reference purposes (**"6baf88a7-eb19-4225-80be-50561871cd51"** in **Print result** below)

Many thanks in advance.

Code:

```
Incorporation = driver.find_element_by_id('incorporationPlace')
print(Incorporation)
```

Print result:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement(session="e09c3d486345c4dbd761a5c308709e03", element="6baf88a7-eb19-4225-80be-50561871cd51")>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The question is not clear, please be very specific and detail your problem in a simple, coherent and easy to understand manner.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium will create a reference to each of the element it's going to interact in the browser session. If you look at the below line

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement(session="e09c3d486345c4dbd761a5c308709e03", element="6baf88a7-eb19-4225-80be-50561871cd51")>
```

<kbd>session</kbd> will hold the current browser session id and

<kbd>element</kbd> will store the `element` reference` and this will change each time element loads on the page. As selenium will assign new reference id when the content is reloaded. You don't have to worry on this reference id and all you have to do is

```
print(Incorporation.text)
```